# Error MultinomialNB is expecting XXX features as input

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Running into an error when trying to use the built model for predictions. Training the model and scoring with test data worked perfectly fine. However when when trying to predict, I run into an error which states MultinomiaNB is expecting XXX features as input.

As the majority of my data is text data and not all rows have data in the respective columns, I cleaned the data up using regex and filled all `None` values with "". I then used custom classes with `CountVectorizer` and `tfidfTransformer` for processing the text columns.

```
train_data, test_data = train_test_split(Full_data,test_size=0.53)


# Using column transformer for data
class TextProcessor(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        self.text_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('count_vectoriser', CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 5))),
        ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer())    ])
        
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return  self.text_transformer.fit_transform(X.squeeze()).toarray()
        
class WordProcessor(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        self.text_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('count_vectoriser', CountVectorizer(analyzer='char', ngram_range=(1, 15))),
        ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer())    ])
        
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return  self.text_transformer.fit_transform(X.squeeze()).toarray()

classifier = MultinomialNB()
      
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('Lyric', TextProcessor(), ['Lyric']),
        ('Meaning', TextProcessor(), ['Meaning']),
        ('Song_title', WordProcessor(), ['Song_Title']),
        ('short_name', WordProcessor(), ['short_name'])])

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
    ('classifier', classifier)])

tuned_parameters = {'kernel':['linear','rbf'],'gamma':[0.001,0.0001],
                    'C':[1,10,100,1000]}

pipe.fit(train_data, train_data['Category'])
pipe.score(test_data, test_data['Category'])
```

out[1]: 0.9710743801652892

```
output = pipe.predict(Full_data)
```

ValueError: X has 291656 features, but MultinomialNB is expecting 172382 features as input.

Comment: Check the shapes of `train_data` and `test_data` as well as the shapes of their labels. If I remember correctly TfIdf and count vectorizer do not produce equally sized vectors for the text. Which is why shapes may differ

Comment: I thought that by performing the column transformation and defining the columns in the preprocessing, then the number of columns wouldn't mater. Am I assuming wrongly? The shapes of `train_data` and `test_data` are (2360 x 10) & (2662 x 10) respectively. The data contains a lot of category binaries (mature/not, english/not, etc) as well as a couple text columns. The text columns are what the model needs to process.